# AJAX request fires twice on submitting a form

Tags: jquery

I wrote the following JQUERY code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('#incidentForm').submit(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       var incidentLatitudeValue = $('#incidentLatitude').val();
       $.post('ajax/test.php', {
           incidentLatitude: incidentLatitudeValue
       }, function(data){
           console.log(e.target);
           console.log(data);
       });
   });
});
```

This should be triggered, when the form submit button is being hit:

```
<div>
    <form id="incidentForm" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputLatitude" class="col-sm-1 control-label">Latitude</label>
            <div class="col-sm-11">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="incidentLatitude" name="inputLatitude" placeholder="Latitude">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputLongitude" class="col-sm-1 control-label">Longitude</label>
            <div class="col-sm-11">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="inputLongitude" placeholder="Longitude">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10">
                <button name="submit" id="incidentSubmit" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="return false">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

When I log the output in the JAVASCRIPT console in chrome I get the feedback that XHR finished loading twice.

```
XHR finished loading: POST "http://api.mf.de/public/ajax/test.php".
XHR finished loading: POST "http://api.mf.de/public/ajax/test.php".
```

I don't see in my JQUERY code the issue for that. The submit button ID is only given once in my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`.submit()`](http://api.jquery.com/submit) instead of `.click()`. Also stop default action by `preventDefault()`

```
$('my-form-and-not-button').submit(function (e) { 
  e.preventDefault();
  // i promise to do the rest of my stuff here
});
```

Comment: I changed the code to your suggestion. See my edit in the post. But now nothing happens at all anymore, even though I got the post method called.

Comment: please remove `return false` for the button and try again

Comment: I removed it, and now it submits again. But again twice

Comment: Yeah it works so far regarding the submission. But the console returns the XHR finished loading message twice and even when I check the network transmission, test.php is called twice and returning a 200 OK twice

Comment: if it is possible show us your live site so that we can figure out quickly. Otherwise, please make sure there are no two event handlers for the for submit

Comment: I checked as well for the doubled submit event handlers and found none.

Comment: you included `main.js` twice. Once as `javascripts/main.js` and second time as `../public/javascripts/main.js`. So two events are attached

Comment: Wow... totally looked in the wrong direction. Thank you Djiraj! Just for learning purposes: How did you track that down?

Comment: I basically used chrome developer tools. I did an Inspect element and then Deleted all the other elements on the page. Now the page just has the form and scripts. Then I looked at how and where the scripts are being loaded. Then i found that there are two main.js included

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the submit type of the button instead and handle all the click yourself or use .submit instead of click as @Dhiraj mentioned.